# CodeIgniter app with php 5.6 however i have sever with php 7.4 a shared hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, digital-ocean

I have a CodeIgniter app with php 5.6 however i have sever with php 7.4 a shared hosting so i am unable to deploy the lower version app on my server. Is there a way to do it??

I have tried hosting it on cloud digital ocean as well failed

Comment: From your question there is no clear problem statement, however in general, you can make the PHP 5.6 code forward compatible with PHP 7.4, and then it works. This is also a recommended approach.

Comment: Since you didn't share what caused the failure, or any relevant code, we can only give you the most general advice. As per the above comment, to make it work you will need to make changes to the code so it doesn't cause errors in the newer PHP version. Please see [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your specific issue, if you want some meaningful help on some aspect of the problem. Thanks.